# Java: FileReader lendo número que não está no arquivo

Tags: java, arquivo, loop, matriz

Eu tenho esse TXT:

```
1,2,4,8,7
45,18,27,35,44
17,45,2,8,6
```

E desejo ler esta matriz para uma matriz em Java. Eis o código:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){


        double[][] pesos = null;
        String valorFinal = "";
        String caracterAAdicionar = null;
        Double valorAAdicionar = null;

        try{
            FileReader arq = new FileReader("Entrada.txt"); 
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);

            pesos = new double[3][5];
            /* Lendo matriz */
            for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){


                    if(j==4)                                                     //se estou no último valor da linha...
                           pesos[i][j] =Double.parseDouble(lerArq.read());              //...apenas leio esse valor
                    else{
                        System.out.println(lerArq.read());
                        caracterAAdicionar = String.valueOf(lerArq.read());
                        while (!caracterAAdicionar.equals(",")){
                            valorFinal = valorFinal + caracterAAdicionar;
                            lerArq.read();
                        }
                    }
                pesos[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(valorFinal);   
                }
            }
                    arq.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException f){
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(InputMismatchException f){
                /*System.out.print("Erro ocorreu em: " + i + " " + j);*/
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(IOException f){
                /*System.out.print("Erro ocorreu em: " + i + " " + j);*/
                f.printStackTrace();
            }
}
```

Problema: no While ( `while (!caracterAAdicionar.equals(",")){` ), o programa entra em loop infinito. Então, para debugar, dou um print em `lerArq.read(`) antes de entrar neste loop pela 1ª vez(como já está no código). E o resultado?

```
49
```

Sim, 49.E, no loop, o programa fica imprimindo "49" para sempre.

Mas de onde raios ele tirou esse número?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há duas coisas que você precisa ter em mente referente ao método `read`da classe BufferedReader:

- Ele lê apenas um caractere no arquivo;
- O retorno do método é um inteiro.

Cada caractere tem sua respectiva representação em decimal, você pode ler mais sobre isso em: [ASC II - Wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)

Como o primeiro caractere do seu arquivo é o '1' (note que ele é um caractere no seu arquivo e não um número) e o número '1' é representado pelo número 49 no sistema decimal (como você pode ver na tabela ASC II do link acima), então como o método retorna um inteiro esse é o motivo do número 49 estar aparecendo.

Com relação ao loop infinito, ele ocorre pois você está comparando se a variável `caracterAAdicionar` é diferente da "," (vírgula). Como seu primeiro caractere é o '1', a condição vai ser verdadeira e entrar no loop, o problema é que dentro do loop você em nenhum momento muda o valor da variável `caracterAAdicionar` ou estabelece uma condição de parada.

Para evitar problemas, o melhor seria que você utilizasse o método `readline()` de BufferedReader para ler linha por linha do seu arquivo e depois obter um array de elementos da linha que será delimitado pela ',' (vírgula) com o método `split`da classe String, nesse caso seu código ficaria assim:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){


        double[][] pesos = null;
        String valorFinal = "";
        String caracterAAdicionar = null;
        Double valorAAdicionar = null;

        try{
            FileReader arq = new FileReader("Entrada.txt"); 
            BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
            ArrayList <String> numEmString = new ArrayList<String>();

            String linhaArq;

            // Lendo cada linha do arquivo
            while ((linhaArq = lerArq.readLine()) != null) {

                // Pegando cada elemento separado por vírgula no arquivo
                for ( String caracteres : linhaArq.split(",") ){

                    // Adicionando os elementos em um ArrayList
                    numEmString.add(caracteres);                    
                }
            }

            pesos = new double[3][5];
            int k = 0;

            for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
                for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ){

                    // Convertendo cada string em Double e armazenando em 'pesos'
                    pesos[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(numEmString.get(k));
                    k++;

                }
            }


            arq.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException f){
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException f){
            /*System.out.print("Erro ocorreu em: " + i + " " + j);*/
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException f){
            /*System.out.print("Erro ocorreu em: " + i + " " + j);*/
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Genial! Apenas  uma dúvida permaneceu:  Se o read() sempre lê os caracteres em ASC||, qual é a utilidade dele?

Comment: O método `read` lê caractere por caractere no arquivo, o retorno do método é um inteiro, mas se você quiser obter o caractere referente em ASC II, você pode usar um cast, por exemplo: `char c = (char) lerArq.read()`. Por outro lado o método `readLine()` lê linha por linha no arquivo, mas muitas vezes você deseja trabalhar com cada caractere do arquivo e não com a linha inteira, nesses casos o método `read()` é bem útil.